# u-boot partition environement variable is always writable regardless of force_ro value

Tags: linux, bootloader, boot-partition, yocto-project

On my platform, the u-boot environment variables can always be modified. Currently, I'm changing the value of `force_ro` to '1', which sets the permission mode to read-only. This change is reflected in the output of the `lsblk` command. However, even after rebooting my device, I can still write values to my boot partition, and the changes persist.

Here are the results of my test:

```
$ cat /sys/block/mmcblk0boot1/force_ro
1
$ fw_setenv primary 2
$ fw_printenv primary
2
```

Here are some details about my platform:

- Cross Compiler: Yocto EL40(Kirkstone)
- Bootloader: u-boot
- U-boot Source: git://github.com/nxp-imx/uboot-imx.git;protocol=https
- U-boot Source Branch: lf_v2022.04
- `fw_setenv` and `fw_printenv` package version in Yocto: libubootenv_0.3.2

Hardware details:

- System Architecture: arm
- CPU: armv8
- SoC: imx8m

Could anyone suggest a solution to make my boot partition read-only based on the value of `force_ro`?

I checked all the u-boot configuration, attempted multiple tests

Answer (score 0):

> u-boot partition environement variable is always writable regardless of force_ro value

That's an unproven assumption on your part, and may be irrelevant.
If instead we make the simple presumption that the U-Boot environment is stored somewhere other than **/dev/mmcblk0boot1**, then the "*results of my test*" are perfectly reasonable.

Where is the U-Boot environment actually stored?
What are the contents of the **/etc/fw_env.config** file?
Did you try using the **strace** command to check which device the **fw_setenv** command in your "*test*" is actually accessed?

IOW are you enforcing protection on the correct partition where the environment variables are actually stored?
Or could the environment be somewhere else, such as in a file file or raw sectors?

You have not provided any proof that this "*boot partition*" is the storage location for U-Boot's environment.
You have not convincingly demonstrated that the `force_ro` attribute is not functioning properly.

---

> Could anyone suggest a solution to make my boot partition read-only based on the value of force_ro?

Why?
What does the system use this "*boot partition*" for?

Your situation and questions all seem to be based on the (faulty) premise that the **/dev/mmcblk0boot1** hardware boot partition of the eMMC is the container for U-Boot's environment.
Did the word "boot" in both names cause you to *assume* that (incorrect) association?

Answer (score 0):

This issue reason was the **libubootenv** commit: https://github.com/sbabic/libubootenv/commit/92949816720d7af2ac722016e7a5b9a85ff141bc. which bypasses the force_ro protection to write.
So for my platform, I am going to edit the source code of  libubootenv

- And about the last replay of this thread, Yes I am sure that the environment variables are stored on `/dev/mmcblk0boot1` as [`dd if=/xx/<uboot>.img of=/dev/mmcblk0boot1 conv=notrunc seek=xx bs=1k`]
- `cat /etc/fw_env.config` has the entry as `/dev/mmcblk0boot1            xx xx`
- strac command of fw_setenv showing as `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mmcblk0boot1",enter code here`

Anyway, the issue's root cause was found and resolved.